# Forcing the touch screen (not display) to sleep on stock Android (no root permissions)

Tags: android, touchscreen

It would be useful for my Android app if I could toggle power to the display's capacitive touchscreen hardware on or off based on app logic while keeping the display's video output feed active; I've looked through the [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) APIs but they seem to only cover controlling the overall system sleep state and the display's video output feed, and [InputDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html) appears to only provide methods for collecting read-only status data.  Intercepting touch events so that the touchscreen is logically ignored (but physically still receives power) is not enough.   Is there any way to disable or power off the touchscreen aspect of the display independent of its video output?  Although I'm currently working with an unrooted stock image (so solutions that could be used by non-system apps would be best), I would also appreciate suggestions that would only work with rooted devices.

Comment: What reason would the system have to permit this? It sounds like it would be particularly easy to write a malicious app if this existed, which is a great reason to not permit it.

Comment: "Intercepting touch events so that the touchscreen is logically ignored (but physically still receives power) is not enough" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare my use case involves some experimental hardware which the touchscreen appears to be (potentially) interfering with